# Memory: In a diagram high address at the top or bottom?

Tags: c, memory, memory-address

I'm learning about memories along with C language. How come in some diagrams the high addresses are located at the top of the diagram  while in other diagrams the high addresses are located at the bottom of the diagram?

**High memory address at the bottom**
[image: High memory address at the bottom]

**High memory address at the top**
[image: High memory address at the top]

Comment: Different people, different opinions, different scenarios.

Comment: There are different architectures and endless possibilities. The memory might be not continuous, but in multiple separate blocks.  Any section may be on a separate device, on the botton, on the top. The addresing might be not continuous. The C language does not enforce any memory structure. The pointers in the program might be differently interpreted by compiler. These images are just examples. Even the Stack might not be on continuous memory, it just depends on malloc implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I think that to really understand this you need to have some knowledge of operating systems and assembly programming. In order to avoid explaining how every architecture on every operating system works, I'll just pick a few in my explanation below. Let's assume that we're running our C-program on the Linux kernel on a desktop with an x86_64 processor (Intel's modern desktop processor architecture).

The Linux kernel splits memory into user and kernel space. User space occupies the higher memory space whereas the kernel space occupies the lower. User space programs that you write in C will therefore have higher memory addresses and be assigned from higher to lower addresses within that space. Since we are running our program on x86_64, that means that we have 64-bit or 8 byte addressing. So whenever you create a new variable on the stack, it will occupy 8-bytes of memory.

Let's assume that we have the following simple function below:

```
long utilfunc(long a, long b, long c)
{
    long xx = a + 2;
    long yy = b + 3;
    long zz = c + 4;
    long sum = xx + yy + zz;

    return xx * yy * zz + sum;
}
```

When you call our C function, a stack frame is created within memory that looks like the following on x86_64 processors:

[image]

Notice how in the cartoon above each variable on our stack is stored 8 bytes away from the next. Notice also the order in which the variables are defined. For example, the `yy` is stored -8 bytes from `xx`. I'm glossing over some details here regarding the picture, but the point that I'm trying to make is that memory is added to the stack from high addresses to low addresses. So when diagrams are drawn with the high address on the bottom and the low address on the top, the meaning is the same but it depends on the authors choice and their own mental model of memory.

References:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64

Answer (score 2):

People put high memory address at the top because they are wrong. I have yet to find a practical reason to do this. People SHOULD put low memory address at the top because that is the way we view memory in debuggers, and is natural way of reading (top to bottom). Furthermore, as the stack grows, in a low address on top viewpoint, it's only  natural to think of a physical stack (like plates) being incremented from bottom up.

You'll use debuggers more often than you'll use a diagram. Why not learn it the way you'll see it for the majority of the time you use it.